# is there a better way to implement this code? it creates a button at first then when clicked, create a div containing a field of multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, containers, event-listener

let's say i am preparing a form to input a new product to database (the product have multiple color, each with its picture) .
the form in my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js" defer></script>

<form action="/something" method="POST">
...
    <button type="button" id="add-color-btn">Add color</button>
    <div id="colors-container">
    </div> 
...
<button type="submit" onclick="return validfuction()">create new product</button>
</form>
```

i set the validfuction() to return 'false', but it was ignored and send the form regardless, so i had to change the form to this:

```
<form action="/something" method="POST" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validfuction();">
...
    "the same"
....
<button type="submit">create new product</button>
</form>
```

because the code in javascript file keep popping up a lot of errors.
the js file:

```
// Get the "Add Color" button and the "Colors" container
const addColorBtn = document.querySelector('#add-color-btn');
const colorsContainer = document.querySelector('#colors-container');

// Add a new color input field when the "Add Color" button is clicked
addColorBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Create a new "color" div
  const colorDiv = document.createElement('div');
  colorDiv.classList.add('color');

  // create a label element
  var colorLabel = document.createElement('label');
  colorLabel.innerText = 'Color: ';
  // create a line break element
  var lineBreak = document.createElement('br');

  // Create the color input field
  const colorInput = document.createElement('input');
  colorInput.type = 'text';
  colorInput.name = 'colors[color][]';
  colorInput.placeholder = 'Color here';
  colorInput.required = true;

  // Create the image input field
  const imageInput = document.createElement('input');
  imageInput.type = 'file';
  imageInput.name = 'colors[image][]';
  imageInput.title= 'Image file here';
  imageInput.accept = '.jpeg, .jpg, .png';
  imageInput.required = true;

  // Create the remove button
  const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  removeBtn.textContent = 'Remove';
  removeBtn.type = 'button';

  // Create the image preview
  let imagePreview = null;


  // Add an event listener to the image input for creating the image preview
  imageInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    // Check if a file was selected
    if (imageInput.files && imageInput.files[0]) {
      // Create a URL for the selected file
      const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageInput.files[0]);

      // Check if an image preview already exists
      if (imagePreview) {
        // Update the image preview's src attribute
        imagePreview.src = imageUrl;
      } else {
        // Create the image preview
        imagePreview = document.createElement('img');
        imagePreview.classList.add('image-preview');
        imagePreview.src = imageUrl;

        // Append the image preview to the color div
        colorDiv.appendChild(imagePreview);
      }
    }
  });

  // Create the show/hide image button
  const showHideBtn = document.createElement('button');
  showHideBtn.textContent = 'Show/Hide Image';
  showHideBtn.type = 'button';

  // Add event listener to toggle the image visibility
  showHideBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Check if imagePreview is not null
    if (imagePreview) {
      imagePreview.classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
  });

  // Add the remove button event listener
  removeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    colorsContainer.removeChild(colorDiv);
  });

  // Add the color and image input fields and the remove button to the "color" div
  colorDiv.appendChild(removeBtn);
  colorDiv.appendChild(colorLabel);
  colorDiv.appendChild(colorInput);
  colorDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
  colorDiv.appendChild(showHideBtn);
  colorDiv.appendChild(imageInput);
  
  // Add the "color" div to the "Colors-container"
  colorsContainer.appendChild(colorDiv);
});
```

without react or jquery, can anyone help find where the problems in the javascript are that makes it ignore my return value in `validfuction()` ?

i was expexting the :`<button type="submit" onclick="return validfuction()">create new product</button>` to be enough for the validation function to execute and stop the form from being send (that did happens, but before i added the multiple field inputs fuction in `<div id="colors-container">`) but it was not and i had to "force" it by calling the preventdefault. the button `<button type="submit" onclick="return validfuction()">create new product</button>` was enough at first before adding the javascript fuction (the one that add new `div` to `colors-container`) with the added inputs in the same field.

as an example: this line isn't suppose to be "let": `let imagePreview = null;` but i had to use an if statement to block multiple images inputs to show in the "imagePreview" (pictures were stacking next to each other instead of changing when i change the input file).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the form with button type submit, it will get submit at any cost except you are using `e.preventDefault();` on `onSubmit` call of form.

Solution for this you have submit form by using js.

`<button type="submit" onClick="return validfuction()">create new product</button>`

and inside validfunction first validate what you want if that gives success then submit form using js.

Here is W3School code link which will help you.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_submit

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: i made some edits so the post can be more understandable because the answer that you gave was not what i was talking about.